# Target child with class inside parent with class

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to target if the focused element is a child with a class **inside** a parent with a class, and add a class to that child. But I can't figure out how to achieve it. How do I target the child with a parent that has the specific class?

This is what I've tried:

```
if (event.keyCode === 9) {
   if (target.closest(".parent")) {
      const child = target.querySelector(".child");
      child.classList.add("new-class");
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<input type="checkbox" /> // hidden input
   <label class="child"> // if this element is tabbed, do stuff
      <span>Icon</span>
   </label>
   <a href="#" class="link">link</a>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve:

if the tabbed (focused) element has class `.child` and is the child of `.parent`, add a class to the child.

Comment: `this.child = document.querySelector(".child");` <-- that is not selecting anything in the parent, that is the entire document. Show your HTML and maybe a working snipplet.

Comment: unclear ! Consider adding the `HTML` part as it would help us understand the issue.

Comment: I've added the markup now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try the `focus-within` CSS selector to style your child:

```
.parent:focus-within .child {
  // style of child here
}
```

as described here: https://css-tricks.com/a-css-approach-to-trap-focus-inside-of-an-element/